# How to return a promise from an action using thunk and useDispatch (react-redux hooks)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I just started exploring react-redux hooks and I was curious how to return a promise if I am using thunk and `useDispatch()`. Essentially I want to achieve the following:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

dispatch(myAction(...args)).then((result) => {
    ...do something with result
});
```

When my action looks like this:

```
const myAction = (arg1, arg2) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        Promise.resolve(arg1 + arg2);
    }
}
```

I've simplified my problem a lot, but that is essentially what I'm dealing with. When I try to dispatch the above action, I get the error `dispatch(...).then` is not a function.

I know redux hooks are pretty new, but I was curious if anybody had gotten this to work or would know a solution. I feel like it should be relatively easy to make this work, but I am at a loss. If you need any more information, let me know. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I've done something very similar a few days ago, please look [this file at line 74](https://github.com/reenan/door-lock/blob/master/src/pages/Store/components/DoorsList/components/DoorContainer.js#L74) that function is defined at line 20 and it resolves after getting an async action dispatch result. The action is [defined here](https://github.com/reenan/door-lock/blob/master/src/actions/index.js#L94) Hope it helps you!

Comment: I believe if you return your promise you can chain:  `return Promise.resolve(arg1 + arg2)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As `dispatch` returns either of two:

1. For sync action (like `dispatch ({type: 'ACTION'})` it will return action object (`{type: 'ACTION'}` in my example)
2. For thunk actions (action creators which return functions) it returns the same result returned from action creator.

So for your case just add `return` statement for your action creator

```
const myAction = (arg1, arg2) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Promise.resolve(arg1 + arg2);
    }
}
```

You can make `myAction` more realistic like so

```
const myAction = (arg1, arg2) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return fetch(/* some request */).then(response => dispatch ({type: 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED', payload: response}));
    }
}
```

In this case also resolved promise will be returned. Contnents of promise will be object `{type: 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED', payload: response}`.

Or you can set arbitrary contents for returned promise like so

```
const myAction = (arg1, arg2) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return fetch(/* some request */).then(response => { 
            dispatch ({type: 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED', payload: response})
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example resolved promise will be returned but which contains `response` inside.

In all cases you can chain like you want

```
dispatch(myAction(...args)).then((result) => {
    ...do something with result
});
```